# How can I merge data from two SQL tables?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.  Table `"alldates"` consists of date column called `"nextdate"`.  Table `"availability"` consists of multiple columns including a date column called `"availdate"`.  The `"alldates"` table primary key is the column `"nextdate"`.  The `"availability"` table primary key is a column called `"event_num"`.

For explanation purposes let's say table `"alldates"` is populated with 16 rows, dates `10/01/2014 through 10/16/2014` and table `"availability"` is populated with 9 rows, like so:

```
Availdate      Event_num   Event Description
10/01/2014  3                    Joe's birthday
10/04/2014 12                   Bill's dentist appt
10/04/2014  5                    Buy pizza
10/05/2014  6                    Clean the house
10/07/2014  7                    Go to theater
10/07/2014  8                    Continue forward
10/09/2014  9                    Mow the grass 
10/11/2014 10                   Take a nap
10/15/2014 11                   Fix the clock
```

I need to create a new table that looks like this:

```
Availdate      Event_num   Event Description
10/01/2014  3                    Joe's birthday
10/02/2014   (from table "alldates")
10/03/2014   (from table "alldates")
10/04/2014 12                   Bill's dentist appt
10/04/2014  5                    Buy pizza
10/05/2014  6                    Clean the house
10/06/2014   (from table "alldates")
10/07/2014  7                    Go to theater
10/07/2014  8                    Continue forward
10/08/2014   (from table "alldates")
10/09/2014  9                    Mow the grass 
10/10/2014   (from table "alldates")
10/11/2014 10                   Take a nap
10/12/2014   (from table "alldates")
10/13/2014   (from table "alldates")
10/14/2014   (from table "alldates")
10/15/2014 11                   Fix the clock
10/16/2014   (from table "alldates")
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a classic left join to me.

```
select a.nextdate as availdate,
b.event_num,
b.event_description
from alldates a
left join availability b
on a.nextdate = b.availdate
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If both the table have same number of columns then you can probably do a `UNION` between them and `order by` the `Availdate` column

```
select * from
(
select Availdate,
Event_num,
Event Description
from alldates

UNION

select Availdate,
Event_num,
Event Description
from availability
) tab    
order by Availdate
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. `LEFT OUTER` tells SQL to include rows from the first table, even if they don't have corresponding entries in the second. "Corresponding" is determined by the *predicate*, which is a condition telling the database how rows in one table are associated with rows in the other.

The below query will select all rows from `alldates`. For those whose `nextdate` matches a row's `availdate` in `availability`, each it will be displayed once per matching row. For those whose `nextdate` doesn't match anything from `availability`, event_num and event_description will be listed as `NULL`.

```
SELECT
    alldates.nextdate,
    availability.event_num,
    availability.event_description
FROM
    ALLDATES
    LEFT JOIN availability
ON alldates.nextdate = availability.availdate;
```